# SEDE query to get all custom close reasons?

Tags: support, data-explorer, custom-close-reasons

Is there a way to pull a list of custom "Other..." close reasons that users have typed from SEDE, preferably including deleting posts?

I'm looking to propose a new close reason on Hardware Recommendations but can't seem to find the data I'm looking for in the data explorer that I need to properly build my case. I don't think what I'm seeing is anecdotal, but I want to be sure.

If it's not available in SEDE, I'll just post a question for the CMs, but I figured I'd try to help myself first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data is not in SEDE as such. The Other option is a sub-reason under off-topic. SEDE doesn't have the sub-close reasons, let alone the custom reason that users can offer there.

Try the 10K tools [close stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) page:

[image]

Near the bottom you'll find the creative texts some close voters come up with.

Based on the idea from Glorfindel you could [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/hardwarerecs/query/1075370) for the comments on questions that were closed and not deleted:

```
;with reasons as (
select distinct p.id,
       c.text
from posts p
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
inner join comments c on c.postid = p.id
where ph.posthistorytypeid = 10 -- close
and ph.comment in ('2', '102') -- off-topic
and (c.text like 'I''m voting to close this question as off-topic%'
-- or c.text like 'I''m closing this question%'
)
)

select text
    , count(*) [time used]
from reasons
group by text
order by count(*) desc
```

That gives 27 cases in Hardware Recommendations:

[image: list with common custom close reasons]

Answer (score 3):

As @rene says, this is in the 10k tools, but only for the last 90 days:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days

If you need a longer period, you could write a SEDE query selecting comments, since almost all of them will start with

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

This doesn't work for deleted posts, though.

Comment: I can't see that even though I have 23K rep on SO; to be clear, that's only accessible to 10k privilege on Meta.SE (which is hardly anyone). Can you please make an SO-only one accessible to SO users like me? I think few people will want an SE-network-wide one rather than for specific site like SO.

Comment: Just replace `meta.stackexchange.com` in the URL with `stackoverflow.com`, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days It's not network-wide, it's a site-specific page already.